# Does 'flight attendant' refer to men, woman or both?

Tags: meaning

In English there are some words which just refer to men, like Sir, or just refer to women, like Madam.
Does ***flight attendant*** refer to women, men or both?

Comment: It's gender-neutral so it refers to both.  You'd be better asking this at the English Language Learners stack: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29323/how-should-i-describe-a-woman-who-serves-food-and-drinks-on-a-plane

based on the link that is for both men and women

Comment: @moreroz That's correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to both. *Steward* and *stewardess* are gendered and were historically more commonly used, especially in the period when the job was much more strongly associated with one sex or the other (at first a strictly male-only job, then later a strongly female-dominated job, before returning some way toward being more balanced). These days *flight attendant*, *cabin attendant* and *cabin crew* are preferred precisely because they aren't gendered terms.